# rails send multiple commands at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How can you create multiple scaffolds at once at the rails command line?

so that these commands could be send at once

```
rails g scaffold person  name:string
rails g scaffold adress  street:string person:references
rails g scaffold website url:string person:references
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generators are initialized from scripts/rails. [You could specify your own generator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html) which just chains generators, or use something like rake to invoke multiple commands, or use a shell script if you want them literally chained.